# How To Display Numeric Field in SharePoint with Text After but Keep Field Numeric

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json-formatting

I am looking for the JSON code to enter in a numeric SharePoint List field that will display text after the number. Excel has this option, you just choose to format the cell as a number and in customer enter in: #.0 "days" and thus your field will show, for example when you enter in the number twelve, it will display "12 days" but yet the field is still a numeric value.

How do I get a numeric SharePoint list field to do this?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint online will let you do this without JSON. You can configure your Number field to have a custom postfix. You can do this by editing the number column and under the Preview section are a few examples of prefixes and postfixes that can be used. For your case, select **Custom**. Then choose the **R** so it is on the right and use word `days` for the symbol:

[image: Custom Number Symbol Configuration]